# Flow typing with bindActionCreators is not working on mapDispatchToProps

Tags: react-redux, flowtype

Here is my dispatch props definition:

```
type DispatchProps = {
  selectRow: (index: number) => void,
  loadData: (fetchArgs: FetchArgs) => void,
};

// This works
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch: Dispatch): DispatchProps => ({
  selectRow: (selectedRowIndex: number) => dispatch(actions.selectRow(selectedRowIndex)),
  loadData: (fetchArgs: FetchArgs) => dispatch(actions.loadData(fetchArgs)),
});

// This doesn't work
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch: Dispatch): DispatchProps => bindActionCreators({
  selectRow: actions.selectRow,
  loadData: actions.loadData,
}, dispatch);
```

Flow complains saying that:

```
SelectRowAction [1] is incompatible with undefined [2] in the return value of property `selectRow`.
```

It's like if `bindActionCreator` type definition is attempting to return the action creators return value (in this case, `SelectRowAction`), but that doesn't make any sense because those values are passed to `dispatch`, and dispatch should be returning `undefined`.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

I've had same issue, you need to define returning type of your functions in DispatchProps instead `void`
For example:

```
type DispatchProps = {
  selectRow: (index: number) => SelectRowActionType,
  loadData: (fetchArgs: FetchArgs) => LoadDataActionType,
};
```